# c# In parallelly getting and working with data

Tags: c#

I don't know if i have described the Question Title really well but here is what i want .

I have a method that return Some data from web and add it to a List .

```
public List<info> infos()
{
   List<info> datas = new List<info>();
   foreach(//)
   {
     1) // send Api Request 
     2) // getting Data 
     3) // Added it to the List 
   }
   return datas;
}
```

I have a ListView in my GUI i want to be able to add the Info retreived from the api and added it to the list one by one instead of returning the whole full List Because **IT TAKES SO LONG TO LOAD**

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you're asking, never mind what specific solution would answer your question. Obvious options include changing the method to an iterator (i.e. return `IEnumerable<info>` and use `yield return` after each response), making the method `async` and having it populate an `ObservableCollection<info>` passed to it, or using `Progress<T>` to allow the caller to decide how to deal with each response as it comes, to name just a few. Please put some more effort into this, and post a question only when you can provide a good [mcve] and explain what _specific_ help you need.

Comment: you need to add to the ui control in the loop and refresh the ui

Comment: and theres no need to SHOUT

Comment: is this winforms or wpf

Comment: You really should show the actual code you're using. That makes it much easier for us to give you a good answer. Please show us the code that TAKES SO LONG.

Answer (score 0):

Use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (NuGet "System.Reactive").

Then you can do this:

```
public IObservable<info> infos()
{
    return
        from n in Observable.Range(0, 100)
        from i in Observable.FromAsync(() => ApiRequestInfo(n))
        select i;
}

public Task<info> ApiRequestInfo(int index)
{
    // implement your actual API call here.
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => new info() { Index = index });
}

public class info
{
    public int Index;
}
```

Now, to consume the data you do this:

```
IDisposable subscription =
    infos()
        .ObserveOn(this) // WinForm: `this` is form
        .ObserveOnDispatcher() // WPF
        .Subscribe(i =>
        {
            /* use `i` in your UI */
        });
```

You need to choose `.ObserveOn(this)` or `.ObserveOnDispatcher()` depending on your UI.

This code will do all of the thread marshalling for you.